# Page Events IDE support

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ide

Asp.net page events (such as `Page_Init()` and `Page_PreRender()`) are without a IDE visual support, (= I cannot see Page events in the properties as i see web controls events - like a `TectChanged()` event).

The only way to use them is to code them manually like this:

```
void Page_Init(){
  //Place your Page_Init code here
}
```

Am i right?
There is no reference to these events in the aspx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically anything under the Life Cycle events section listed here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.90%29.aspx can have an override function.

Or you can reference `System.Web.UI.Page` events here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx

The Page itself is a class and you can reference just about anything from the MSDN library.